# Else statement is overwriting my if statement in JS chronometer

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm trying to create a chronometer, It works well when I don't add the typical zeroes before the 1 digit numbers, but when trying to create a logic that removes the zero it makes my code not work properly.

Here is a working snippet:

```js
        var n = 0;

        var m = 0;
        var h = 0;

        var n = ( n < 2 ) ? n = "0" + 2 : n.slice(-2) ;


        var scrubberCounter = document.getElementById("scrubberCounter");
        
          setInterval(function () {
              if(n.toString().length < 2 && m.toString().length < 2){
                scrubberCounter.innerHTML = h + ":" + "0" + m + ":" + "0" + n;

              }else{
                scrubberCounter.innerHTML = h + ":" + m + ":" +n;
              }

            n++;
            if (n ===20) {
        
              if (m < 20) {
                m++;
              } else {
                m = 0;
                h++;
              }
              n = 0;
            }
          }, 300);
```

```html
    <table style='border: 1px solid orange; background: white;'><tr><td><font color='red' id='scrubberCounter'></font></td></tr></table>
```

How can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You check that *both* values have length < 2.

Fixing `n` and `m` are not related; each must be handled separately.

```js
var n = 0
var m = 0
var h = 0

var n = ( n < 2 ) ? n = "0" + 2 : n.slice(-2)

var scrubberCounter = document.getElementById("scrubberCounter")
        
setInterval(function () {
  let sN = n < 10 ? `0${n}` : n
  let sM = m < 10 ? `0${m}` : m

  scrubberCounter.innerHTML = `${h}:${sM}:${sN}`

  n++;
  if (n === 20) {
    if (m < 20) {
      m++
    } else {
      m = 0
      h++
    }

    n = 0
  }
}, 50)
```

```html
<table style='border: 1px solid orange; background: white;'><tr><td><font color='red' id='scrubberCounter'></font></td></tr></table>
```

Noting that there are other ways to do this; I kept your code as presented.